# Google Plus count does not increment after sharing the post

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url allows us to share the content but doesn't allow to increment the 'plus one count' .

Comment: If it's urgent you might want to spend a little more time improving your question so that people can answer it more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the code as mentioned in the example not just used the link.

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Source: http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The share URL you are using is not a supported Google+ API. It typically happens after you +1 a URL in a popup but because you are using it directly it skips actually +1'ing the URL. If you want to include +1's use the +1 button as @benni_mac_b's answer states.